# When did acronyms first appear?

Tags: language-evolution, spoken-language, abbreviations

Acronyms are abbreviations that are read as whole words rather than letter by letter — or in other words, they are words formed from initials of a phrase.
"NATO" and "laser" are two examples.

I have seen abbreviations used in Latin, but I get the impression that they are often expanded to whole in speech or read as an abbreviation letter by letter.
Not all abbreviations are suitable for acronyms.
I will not try to pronounce "SPQR" as a single word…

Modern Latin has some acronyms, for example the name "NATO", but I wonder how new this phenomenon is.
**When did acronyms first appear in Latin?**
How do we know how they were read out?
(Maybe they were declined?)

I have no guess as to what the answer might be, so any examples of acronyms with timing and explanation are welcome.

Comment: In Christian times, (Greek) "ichthus" (Iesus Christos Theou Huios Soter) comes to mind, as well as Latin "INRI" (Iesus Nazarenus Rex Iudaeorum).

Comment: @brianpck, I had forgotten about the Greek fish. Do we have a reason to believe that INRI was pronounced as a two-syllable word rather than expanding all the words or reading the letters one by one? If yes, that would make a good answer.